# Detect if the last selected email has been marked as read and prompt to save

Tags: vba, events, outlook

My outlook VBA code aims at doing the following:
In the event of selection change (i.e. say the user clicks on a different email in the inbox)

```
If [the previously selected email was originally 'Unread' and just became 'Read'] Then
Prompt the user to save the previous email
Else
Do Nothing
End If
```

To do that I used the Explorer_SelectionChange event. The problem I'm facing is that outlook takes about 1 to 2 seconds before it marks the previous email as read! My code gets executed before these 2 seconds pass. Hence it always sees the previous email as unread! :(

I tried to introduce a pause to my Sub but it didn't work. Outlook waits until my code finishes including the pause before it in turn waits 1 to 2 seconds and then mark the previous email as read.

So in summary my question is: Is there an Event that identifies when the previously selected email is marked as Read?? (PS: I tried MailItem.Read Event but it is also instantaneous and applies to all 'read and unread' emails]

Here is the part of my code that specifically tries to achieve the above described functionality:

```
Public WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim Flag As Integer
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objItem As Object

Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

'Identify the status of the selected email at startup
For Each objItem In myOlExp.Selection
    If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
        Set oMail = objItem
    End If
Next

If oMail.UnRead Then
    Flag = 1 'Means Current selection is an unread email
Else
    Flag = 0 'Means Current selection has been read before
End If

End Sub


Private Sub myOlExp_SelectionChange()
'If previous selected email was Unread
If Flag = 1 Then
    If oMail.UnRead = False Then
        MsgBox "previous email has just been read do you want to save?"
        '^^This is where the problem happens: the previously selected email is always seen as read by the code
        'because Outlook takes 1-2 seconds after the selection change event before it marks the email as read!!
    Else
        MsgBox "Previous email still marked as unread, do nothing"
        '^^I am always getting this outcom when I change selection from an unread email to another email!
    End If

    'Now identify the status of the newly selected email
    For Each objItem In myOlExp.Selection
        If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
            Set oMail = objItem
        End If
    Next

    If oMail.UnRead Then
        Flag = 1 'Means Current selection is an unread email
    Else
        Flag = 0 'Means Current selection has been read before
    End If

Else
    ' Flag = 0 i.e previous email was already read
    ' Identify the status of the newly selected item.
    For Each objItem In myOlExp.Selection
        If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
            Set oMail = objItem
        End If
    Next
    If oMail.UnRead Then
        Flag = 1
    Else
        Flag = 0
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I hope I managed to formulate my question clearly! Any help is most appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once you set Flag = 1, oMail.UnRead status does not matter.

```
If Flag = 1 Then

    ' Remove this test
    'If oMail.UnRead = False Then

        MsgBox "...
```

Comment: Thanks I don't know why I was hung up on checking the status of the previous email. However,  there are situations where the previously selected email could be left marked 'unread' if the user have changed the default settings of outlook. This works for now though. Thanks.